# Use of enum in apollo server 4

Tags: enums, graphql, apollo-server

I am learning to build a GraphQL API, and I'd like to usethe type `enum`

In my database, the data looks like this :

```
const missions = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Mission 1",
    status: "in progress",
  },
];
```

And and my schema and resolvers like this :

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  enum Status {
    NOTSTARTED
    INPROGRESS
    COMPLETED
  }
  type Mission {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    status: Status!
  }

  type Query {
    missions: [Mission]
    mission(id: ID!): Mission
  }

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    missions() {
      return missions;
    },
    mission(_, args) {
      return missions.find((mission) => {
        return mission.id === args.id;
      });
    },
  },
};
`;
```

In Apollo explorer, when I execute the query

```
query($missionId: ID!){
  mission(id: $missionId) {
    id
    name
    status
  }
}
```

I get the error ""Enum "Status" cannot represent value: "in progress"".

If I change the field in my database to `status:"INPROGRESS"` , i can execute the query, but I don't think that is the solution.

I am reading Apollo Server documentation about Enums, and I cannot see clear a way to assign a value to every value from the enum list, so that value matches the value from my database.